# How do you say a countable turn out?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, adjectives

Very few people attended the concert you can count them as opposed to countable because it's possible to count.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

> **[count something on the fingers of one hand](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/count-something-on-the-fingers-of-one-hand)**: Used to emphasize the small number of a particular thing: you can count the exceptions on
>   the fingers of one hand
>
> **More example sentences:**
>
> Throughout the eighteen years of Conservative government, the total
>   number of Cabinet ministers with children in the state system could be
>   counted on the fingers of one hand.
>
> The real favourites for the title can be counted on the fingers of one
>   hand, and first on everyone's list, invariably, is Hewitt.
>
> He said he could count such days on the fingers of one hand.

**Your sentence could be**: Very few people attended the concert you can *count them on the fingers of one hand*.

Though it can be an exaggeration, the message about extremely low attendance will be clear.